# htaccess: condition to check if string is in request

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need to write a condition for a mod rewrite URL rule to detect which page is being executed.

The `RewriteRule` I'm using works fine, but the problem is that I need to use the same rule for two different URLs.

```
RewriteRule ^testing/([^/]*)$ /index.php?url=$1&name=&submit=submit [NC,L] 
RewriteRule ^testing/([^/]*)$ /test.php?url=$1&name=&submit=submit [NC,L]
```

Without any rewrite conditions set, when adding `example.com/testing/` in the browser the first `RewriteRule`in `htaccess` is used whether I'm on `index.php` or `test.php`.

Heres a few of the `RewriteCond` I've tried:
     `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} /test.php$`
     `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ (test\.php)/ [NC]`
     `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(test\.php)/ [NC]`
     `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /test\.php/`

And Heres the full htaccess file code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
## check if on index.php ##
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*\/index.php\/.*$ ## not working ##
## if on index.php do this ##
RewriteRule ^testing/([^/]*)$ /index.php?url=$1&name=&submit=submit [NC,L]  
## check if on test.php ##
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*\/test.php\/.*$ ## not working ##
## If on test.php do this ##
RewriteRule ^testing/([^/]*)$ /test.php?url=$1&name=&submit=submit [NC,L]
```

How can I get the first (index.php) `rewriteRule` to work on `index.php`, but when on the `test.php` page ignore the first rule and use the second one?

Thanks :)

EDIT: Just to clarify. I don't want to redirect. I just want to change the value of `testing/` based on what page I'm on. As I mentioned the rewriteRule already works fine.

Comment: You can't do that. With your link `/testing/...` it's not possible to know if it's for `index.php`or for `test.php`. You can change your link with a code or name `testingi`and `testingt` for exemple, or `testing/i...` etc.

Comment: Thats what the condition is supposed to be for. The idea is if `index.php` is in the script name then execute the rule, if not then don't. If `test.php` is in the script name then execute that rule. if not then don't .

Comment: In the `%{HTTP_REFERER}` url ? Because you rewrite your link, when you use it, not the script name...

Comment: No, I don't want to rewrite the script name. I want to test if the script name contains a string. If it does then rewrite the URL.

Comment: You don't understand... Apache rewrite your link when you use it. Not when you run your script. You can sometimes possibly read the  script name in `%{HTTP_REFERER}` when the user click on the link (sorry for my bad English)

Answer (score 0):

```
## If on index.php ##
RewriteRule    "^/index\.php$"  "/index.php?url=$1&name=&submit=submit" [R,L]
```

Try this

Comment: I'm sorry @Elby I think you may have misunderstood slightly. The rule works fine. The URL after mod rewrite would look like: `example.com/testing/youtube.com` (youtube.com is just an example)

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On

#Checking if /index.php/ apears in URI
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)\/index\.php\/(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ testing/index.php?url=$1&name=&submit=submit [NC]
```

this will show **index.php?url=sth1/index.php/sth2** output instead of **sth1/index.php/sth2**

Good luck

Comment: I don't wish to redirect. I need to change the value of `testing/` based on the page I'm on.

Comment: @turrican_34, Can you explain more with an example please?

Comment: I've updated the comments in the full htaccess code.Which part don't you understand?

Comment: @turrican_34, what is the user request exactly and which file do you want to be showed up?

Comment: As I mentioned I need to basically change the value of `testing/`.
If `index.php` is in the script name/request (condition) then use the rewriteRule: `RewriteRule ^testing/([^/]*)$ /index.php?url=$1&name=&submit=submit [NC,L] `.

If `test.php` is in the script name/request (condition) then use the rewriteRule: 'RewriteRule ^testing/([^/]*)$ /test.php?url=$1&name=&submit=submit [NC,L]'.

Comment: @turrican_34, don't repeat the questin. give me user request url and your file. I think your rule must be changed too. if I understood correctly you want to change `http://example.com/testing/index.php/something` to `http://example.com/index.php?url=something&...` . am I right?

Comment: @turrican_34, I change the answer somehow, check if it solves your problem